# Convert IP-Address to Binary (UInt32)

Tags: ios, swift

I have an IP address in a Stringformat, so `"192.168.0.1"`.

I want to convert this string to a binary/bit version, so that I get a `Uint32` out of it. In this case `16820416`

I've found multiple tutorials online how to convert a bit version to a String like here:

```
let ipAddress = 16820416

public var ipAddressString: String {
    var bytes = [UInt32]()
    bytes.append(self.ipAddress & 0xFF)
    bytes.append((self.ipAddress >> 8) & 0xFF)
    bytes.append((self.ipAddress >> 16) & 0xFF)
    bytes.append((self.ipAddress >> 24) & 0xFF)

    return "\(bytes[0]).\(bytes[1]).\(bytes[2]).\(bytes[3])" //192.168.0.1
}
```

**My Question: How can I do the exact opposite of this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`inet_pton()`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/inet_pton.3.html) function ...

> ... converts a presentation format address (that is, printable form as held in a
>        character string) to network format (usually a struct in_addr or some other internal binary representation, in network byte order).

Example:

```
let addrString = "192.168.0.1"
var addr = in_addr()
if inet_pton(AF_INET, addrString, &addr) == 1 {
    let ipAddress = addr.s_addr

    print(ipAddress) // 16820416
    print(String(format:"%#08x", ipAddress)) // 0x100a8c0
} else {
    print("invalid address")
}
```

All socket address structures use "network byte order" (= big-endian).
If you want the IP address in the host byte order (= little-endian)
then use

```
    let ipAddress = UInt32(bigEndian: addr.s_addr)

    print(ipAddress) // 3232235521
    print(String(format:"%#08x", ipAddress)) // 0xc0a80001
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `components(separatedBy:)` to divide the string into 4 parts. Then add each part in turn into a total, shifting the previous total by 8 bits each time:

```
let ipString = "192.168.1.12"
let values = ipString.components(separatedBy: ".").flatMap{Int($0)}

var result = 0
for aValue in values {
  result = result << 8 + aValue
}
print(String(format:"%X", result))
```

Or going "full functional:"

```
let ipString = "192.168.1.12"
let result = ipString.components(separatedBy: ".").flatMap{Int($0)}.reduce(0, 
{ x, y in
  x << 8 + y
})
```

Or making it as short and cryptic as possible:

```
let ipString = "192.168.1.12"
let result = ipString.components(separatedBy: ".").flatMap{Int($0)}.reduce(0) { $0 << 8 + $1 }
```

Comment: My result is `3232235521` and not `16820416 ` what it should be

Comment: @JohnSmith you just need to use UInt32 bigEndian initializer. Btw it was already very well explained by Martin's answer

Comment: @DuncanC Worked